# 2005 Subaru Forester Overheating

Tags: subaru, overheating, forester

2005 subaru forester x 77k miles replaced both head gaskets, timing belt thermostat and radiator. I purged the system also. I turned on the heater and no heat just cold air. The lower radiator hose and the heater hoses are also cold. 
Thanks Tom

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you replace the water pump?

Comment: Has the cooling system been pressure tested? That is similar behavior to low coolant. You could still be leaking.